# Get real-time data from SQL Server Compact databases

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce

How to get real-time data from SQL Server Compact databases (*.sdf file) using Visual Studio 2010, WinForm, C#.NET, .NET Framework 4.0 to update Controls (Label and DataGridView).

Comment: By real-time, you mean you want the application to be updated every time there are changes in the database?

Comment: yes, is that possible? like in SQL Server 2005 or higher.

Comment: For SQL Server Compact, you will have to do polling, depending on how you structure tables, you can do some leightweight polling

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions for this problem. On the database side, you can use [Event Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190427%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) where you can subscribe to the changes occurring in the database and handle the events. Another would be polling, that is monitoring your database by constantly running queries and checking changes.

Comment: As far as I know it can be perform to SQL Server 2005 or higher, I don't with  SQL Server Compact databases, but if you know how to implement it to SQL Server Compact databases could you tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

you can use longpoll read this  site 
[Long poll for read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling)